# magento not installing on ubuntu 14.04 and database is not configuring

Tags: magento, installation, parse-error

While installing magento on ubuntu 14.04, i am getting the following error :

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93"

unable to navigate on Magento's installation wizard. what should i do?

Comment: please upgrade php to 5.6.16 or greater hope this helps.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the official prerequisites for you magento version. http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html
And check if you are using the correct PHP version.